# vector pop_back causing heap-buffer-overflow error

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, stack

I'm trying to make a function to validate the parenthesis problem, this function runs well on my machine, but it causing **"heap-buffer-overflow"** error on leetcode machine when I call **vector.pop_back()**. Here's the code:

```
int isValid(string s){
    vector<char> st;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(s[i] == '(') st.push_back(s[i]);
        else{
            if(st.back() == '(') st.pop_back(); //this line triggered the error
            else return 0;
                
        }
    }
    return (st.size() == 0);
}
```

I already solved this by changing the vector into string, but I'm still wondering how can this happened, any explanation anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Calling [std::vector::back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) on an empty vector is *undefined behavior*.

> Calling back on an empty container causes undefined behavior.

(*The same holds for `std::vector::pop()`, but at that point your program is already in an invalid state if the container was empty*).

Therefore, the expression `st.back() == '('` on your code might lead to an invalid program state because the container `st` is not sure being *not* empty.

---

Your code path needs to check the emptiness of the container *before* calling `std::vector::back()`; something like:

```
if (!st.empty() && st.back() == '(')
  st.pop_back();
else
  return 0;
```

**Bonus Note**: the code above exploits logical operators [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). It means that the second operand (i.e., the expression `st.back()`) will not be invoked if the container is empty.

Comment: Thanks, it resolved that way, but how can it cause no error on my machine?

Comment: Technically speaking, an undefined behavior puts your program in an unknown state. From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub): *"undefined behavior - there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program."*. We are used to say that "everything can happen" (in theory, your program might even erase your hard drive, no guarantees are provided on its behavior). In practice, the behavior changes differently for different environment (compiler, hardware architecture, standard library, ...). On your machine the "bad state" is not visible, but present anyway tho.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you didn't assign any element in the vector before checking on the if condition. Try putting :

```
if(st.size()!=0)
{
 if(st.back() == '(') st.pop_back(); 
            else return 0;
}
```

on that piece of code